# Remove duplicates in a csv file based on two columns?

Tags: csv, python-3.x, conditional-statements, duplicates

I have a CSV which must be read and have duplicate values removed before it gets written.

Duplicate value would be based on two columns (date, price) (AND conditional statement). Therefore in the example below row 1, row 2, and row 4 would get written to CSV. Row 3 would qualify as a duplicate (since the same date and price match row 1) and would be excluded (not written to CSV).

```
address      floor       date         price
40 B STREET    18        3/29/2015    2200000
40 B STREET    23        1/7/2015     999000
40 B STREET    18        3/29/2015    2200000
40 B STREET    18        4/29/2015    2200000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a `DictReader` and `DictWriter` to fulfill your task.

```
import csv

def main():
"""Read csv file, delete duplicates and write it."""
    with open('test.csv', 'r',newline='') as inputfile:
        with open('testout.csv', 'w', newline='') as outputfile:
            duplicatereader = csv.DictReader(inputfile, delimiter=',')
            uniquewrite = csv.DictWriter(outputfile, fieldnames=['address', 'floor', 'date', 'price'], delimiter=',')
            uniquewrite.writeheader()
            keysread = []
            for row in duplicatereader:
               key = (row['date'], row['price'])
               if key not in keysread:
                   print(row)
                   keysread.append(key)
                   uniquewrite.writerow(row)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

While not in the standard library, `pandas` is excellent for this sort of thing:

```
import pandas as pd
records = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
deduped = records.drop_duplicates(['date', 'price'])
deduped.to_csv('deduped.csv', index=False)
```

The drawback of this approach is that all of your data is read into memory at once. However, if your dataset fits comfortably in memory, it may be worth the added clarity and expressiveness – especially if you'll be doing additional manipulation of tabular data like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `set` to preserve the written rows and in each iteration check , if that the row has been written just don't write it, and use `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` to rewrite your file :

```
import csv
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import shutil

seen=set()
tempfile = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)

with open('file_name.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
     spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
     for row in spamreader:
         date=row[2]
         if date not in seen:
            spamwriter.writerow(row)
         seen.add(date)
shutil.move(tempfile.name, file_name)
```

Comment: What about price? I only want to exclude if both 'date' AND 'price' values were in a previous record. If it was only date value or price value in previous record then include that. Hence, it must be a conditional statement.

Comment: @user3062459 So just put the `tuple(row[2:])` on `seen` and check it.